# Ip authentication in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

I have Spring Security 4.2.2 in my web-app and configured LDAP based authentication. In addition i also need to authenticate all users with specified ip without log-in form and set the "local_user" role for them. How can i perform that authentication scenario?

upd:
I mean, that "local users" must view the same content as the users that have authorized through login form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using antMatchers like below code:

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Configuration
    public class BasicSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/baseUrl/anything-else/**").hasIpAddress("ipAddressExpression")
    }
}
```

### Updated

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/baseUrl/anything-else/**").access("hasIpAddress('ipAddressExpression') or fullyAuthenticated()");
```

Comment: do you want to say that you are restricting just some of the data depending on user ip address?

Comment: then I think you should use Method level security. check this post:
http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-security/prefilter-postfilter-in-spring-security
or this one
http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-method-security-using-preauthorize-postauthorize-secured-el/
depending on your requirements

Comment: check my updated answer, it will satisfy what you need
"upd: I mean, that "local users" must view the same content as the users that have authorized through login form."